# Making a scratch with parameters to tune on my image texture background

Tags: texturing

Sorry for the stupid question.
I am a new user in Blender.
I am trying to make a plane with only one scratch on it, and I want to set some parameters such as width, length and depth for later tuning. I have my own image texture for the plane's background. However, I can't generate the scratch on it properly. Honestly, I even can't generate scratch on it with procedurally way. I want to make it all with script so that I could make it automatically later. Please give me a hand, I have try it two weeks without any progress. Thanks a lot.

This is what I want.

[image]